# If $n$ is odd, then we need at least n+1 linear operators to span $\mathbb{K}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $n$ is odd, then we need at least n+1 linear operators to span $\mathbb{K}^n$

Let $f_1,...,f_n: \mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ linear operators. For $y \in \mathbb{K}^n$, consider the vectors $f_1 (y),...,f_n(y)$ as rows in an $n \times n$ matrix M. But $\det M$ is a plynomial in $n$ variables, how can I proof that there is a non-trivial zero?

Comment: What does it mean for a collection of linear operators to span $\mathbb{K}^n$?

Comment: $[f_1(y),...,f_n(y)] = \mathbb{K}^n$, ie, $\forall x \in \mathbb{K}^n$, x is a linear combination of $f_1(y),...,f_n(y)$

Comment: Is that supposed to be true for all nonzero $y$?  Is there any restriction on what $\mathbb{K}$ is?

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ row vectors. They give you an $n\times n$ matrix $M$. Then $\det{M}$ is a polynomial in $n^2$ variables since each of the $n$ row vectors has $n$ coordinates. If if the different $f_i(y)$ are linearly independant their span is $\mathbb{K}^n$ and $M$ maps the space bijetively onto itself.